# What exactly does dirty-chai.js do?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai, dirty-chai

The package description for [`dirty-chai`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-chai) is a bit opaque for a newbie:

> Function form for terminating assertion properties

What is an 'assertion property' in this context and what does terminating mean? Why are they not normally "terminated"? I have so many questions. An example without dirty-chai and and an example with, that shows the benefit would be great.

Comment: OK.. so I found the answer by running into the problem it is trying to solve [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2102)... it mentions dirty-chai near the bottom as a solution! So turns out it's about linting??!!

Answer (score 4):

I think one of the key reasons for `dirty-chai` is that it is not considered good practice to [*make assertions on property access*](https://github.com/moll/js-must#beware-of-libraries-that-assert-on-property-access) (at least for some in the JavaScript community).

Without the plug-in `chai` allows you write tests like this:

```js
chai.expect(someFunctionThatReturnsTrue(args)).to.be.true
```

If the test failed, that means `someFunctionThatReturnsTrue(args)` must have been returning something other than `true` and from that you know to start debugging its code to see why.

However, for this test to function, accessing the `true` property needs to *make assertions and disrupt the code execution* if the assertion fails (for example, by throwing an Exception).

Linters generally do not know how property access is done and would by default assume that the accessing of a property will not have any side-effects (i.e. alter the environment), especially not things like throwing exceptions (or cause other control-flow disrupting consequences).

Therefore, if you write `something.true` (without parentheses), the linter will assume that you simply want to access a property of `something` named `true`. If the expression goes nowhere (not used in an assignment, as function parameters, or in other evaluations), the linter would flag this a a potential typo or something else. Therefore, the previous valid case in `chai` will generate a linter error.

And **these kind of linter errors can be useful** in some cases because JavaScript does not complain if you try to access properties that do not exist. For example, what if you do have a typo in your test code?

```js
chai.expect(someFunctionThatReturnsTrue(args)).to.be.ture
                                                  // ~~~~ not `true`, obviously a typo
```

**This test would pass no matter what `someFunctionThatReturnsTrue(args)` returns.** Because accessing `.ture` simply returns `undefined` and will not throw an error. Then you may miss some coding errors in `someFunctionThatReturnsTrue()` if you are forced to ignore these linter errors by `chai`.

Worse, if there is any error, you may assume that it's not in `someFunctionThatReturnsTrue()` because that test (wrongly) passes.

Thus the plugin, `dirty-chai`, by converting assertions by property access (like `.true`) into calling these properties as function (`.true()`) make sure linters will know that these statements can change the control flow:

```js
chai.expect(someFunctionThatReturnsTrue(args)).to.be.true()
// Linter now knows you are expecting something to happen during `.true()` call
// and won't complain anymore
```

And now if you make a typo, the test will fail (by throwing an exception)

```js
chai.expect(someFunctionThatReturnsTrue(args)).to.be.ture()
                                                  // ~~~~ Will throw something like
                                                  // `...to.be.ture is not a function`
```